# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch {} which is an instance of Hash(#70364214688040)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

The following model using "class_name":

```
class Shipment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to  :origin,     :class_name => "Location"
  belongs_to  :destination,:class_name => "Location"
end
```

In my controller I am trying to build a new instance:

```
@shipment = Shipment.new({
"origin" => {"name"=>"12312", "country"=>"US", "city"=>"Cambridge", "state"=>"MA", "postal_code"=>"02138", "address1"=>"Massachusetts Avenue, 1234", "address2"=>"123213"},
"destination" => {"name"=>"12312", "country"=>"US", "city"=>"Cambridge", "state"=>"MA", "postal_code"=>"02138", "address1"=>"Massachusetts Avenue, 1234", "address2"=>"123213"}})
```

the following params gives me error

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Location(#70364217448000) expected, got {"name"=>"12312", "country"=>"US", "city"=>"Cambridge", "state"=>"MA", "postal_code"=>"02138", "address1"=>"Massachusetts Avenue, 1234", "address2"=>"123213"} which is an instance of Hash(#70364214688040)
```

to bypass this, I am using this:

```
@shipment = Shipment.new
@shipment.build_origin      {"name"=>"12312", "country"=>"US", "city"=>"Cambridge", "state"=>"MA", "postal_code"=>"02138", "address1"=>"Massachusetts Avenue, 1234", "address2"=>"123213"}
@shipment.build_destination {"name"=>"12312", "country"=>"US", "city"=>"Cambridge", "state"=>"MA", "postal_code"=>"02138", "address1"=>"Massachusetts Avenue, 1234", "address2"=>"123213"}
```

Then, I tried to include in the model the following:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :origin
accepts_nested_attributes_for :destination
```

but than I got a blank validation that failed.

How can I fix the model to allow the nested attributes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem there is that you were trying to pass in an hash to the writer method for origin and location, and it expects an instance Location.

Long story short, just check out [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

The validation error you're seeing is probably one validation that is not being met. You may want to check the error messages for the shipment and location objects, ex.: `@shipment.errors.messages`

`accepts_nested_attributes_for` will add `origin_attributes=` and `destination_attributes=` writer methods, that will make things work. You'll have to change the hash keys you're passing to `new` from `origin` to `origin_attributes`, and `destination` to `destination_attributes`.

```
class Shipment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :origin, class_name: 'Location'
  belongs_to :destination, class_name: 'Location'

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :origin, :destination
end
```

Then you can use:

```
@shipment = Shipment.new({
  "origin_attributes" => {
    "name" => "12312", "country" => "US", "city" => "Cambridge", "state" => "MA", "postal_code" => "02138", "address1" => "Massachusetts Avenue, 1234", "address2" => "123213"
  },
  "destination_attributes" => {
    "name" => "12312", "country" => "US", "city" => "Cambridge", "state" => "MA", "postal_code" => "02138", "address1" => "Massachusetts Avenue, 1234", "address2" => "123213"
  }
})
```

As a completely unrelated side note, I would call those attributes `source_location` and `destination_location` or similar. Having "location" on the attribute name clearly states that you are talking about locations, and not other things.